# Rotate / Pivot Table To Make One Column Per Unique Value in Grouping Column

Tags: sql-server

Title might be a bit obtuse, I'm having difficulty explaining this concisely.

I have data that looks like this (**SourceTable**):

```
Date        Type    High    Low
2017-01-10  cats    21.4    10.4
2017-01-10  dogs    20.4    8.4
2017-01-20  cats    40.1    21.2
2017-01-20  dogs    20.1    1.0
```

I have approximately 300 different "types" (as in the Type column). The type is a foreign key pointing to a table of all the types.

**Type Table**

```
Type
cats
dogs
```

Not all types are represented on every date.

I want to make the above table look like this (**FlippedTable**):

```
Date        Cats_High    Cats_Low    Dogs_High    Dogs_Low
2017-01-10  21.4         10.4        20.4         8.4
2017-01-20  40.1         21.2        20.1         1.0
```

I have a working solution that uses a WHILE loop in dynamic SQL that builds a temporary table by constantly ALTERing it to add new columns and insert the new data. It works, but it takes a ridiculous amount of time to execute. I feel like my dynamic SQL approach is inefficient and might be improved with a pivot or two.

Certainly we can argue that doing this in the first place is inefficient and silly, but I unfortunately have my reasons.

Here's my dynamic SQL approach:

```
DECLARE @type_counter INT = 0;
DECLARE @date_counter INT = 0;
DECLARE @all_types_total INT;
DECLARE @all_dates_total INT;

DECLARE @current_date DATE;
DECLARE @current_type NVARCHAR(80);
DECLARE @dynamic_sql NVARCHAR(max);

CREATE TABLE #FlippedTable([Date] DATE PRIMARY KEY);

SELECT @all_types_total=COUNT(*) FROM types;

WHILE @type_counter < @all_types_total
BEGIN
    SELECT @current_type=type FROM (
        SELECT
            type,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY type) as [RowNumber]
        FROM SourceTable)
    AS subquery WHERE [RowNumber] = @type_counter;

    SET @dynamic_sql = 'ALTER TABLE #FlippedTable ADD [' + @current_type + '_Low] NUMERIC(7,2) NULL, ['+@current_type+'_High] NUMERIC(7,2)'
    EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @dynamic_sql;

    SELECT @all_dates_total = COUNT(*) FROM SourceTable WHERE type = @current_type;
    WHILE @date_counter < @all_dates_total
    BEGIN
        SELECT @current_date = [Date] FROM (SELECT [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS [RowNumber] FROM SourceTable) AS subquery WHERE [RowNumber] = @date_counter;

        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FlippedTable WHERE [Date] = @current_date)
            BEGIN
                SET @dynamic_sql = 'UPDATE FlippedTable SET [' + @current_type + '_Low] = tb2.[Low], ['+@current_type+'_High] = tb2.[High] FROM FlippedTable AS tb1 INNER JOIN SourceTable AS tb2 ON tb1.Date = tb2.Date WHERE tb2.type = ''' + @current_type + ''' AND tb2.Date = ''' + CAST(@current_date AS nvarchar(50)) + '''';
                EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @dynamic_sql;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @dynamic_sql = 'INSERT INTO FlippedTable ([Date], ['+@current_type+'_Low], ['+@current_type+'_High] FROM SourceTable WHERE type = ''' + @current_type + ''' AND SourceTable.Date = ''' + CAST(@current_date AS nvarchar(50)) + '''';
            END
        SET @date_counter = @date_counter + 1;
    END;
    SET @date_counter = 0;
    SET @type_counter = @type_counter + 1;
END;
```

Additions to the "types" table is very rare. I know all of the types, so I'm okay with hard-coding all of the possible column names if I have to, though its not ideal.

I am hoping that there is a PIVOT solution to this problem that would be better. I haven't been able to wrap my mind around how I could use that tool in this instance. Whatever the better solution is, I feel like it uses a tool I am not presently familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping should be avoided when possible.  Your can get to your desired resutls via some Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select A.Date
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (Type+''_High'',High)
                              ,(Type+''_Low'',Low)
                     ) B(Item,Value)

      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Type+'_High') 
                                                              +','+QuoteName(Type+'_Low') 
                                               From (Select Distinct Type From YourTable) A
                                               Order By 1 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

```
Date        cats_High   cats_Low    dogs_High   dogs_Low
2017-01-10  21.40       10.40       20.40       8.40
2017-01-20  40.10       21.20       20.10       1.00
```

Comment: This works much better than what I had, and it has the virtue of avoiding hardcoding. Thank you! It is going to take me awhile to understand it, there's a few new things for me here: cross apply, Stuff(), QuoteName(), and whatever witchcraft you're invoking with FOR XML Path().

Comment: @MatthewScheffel Happy it helped.  The Stuff() portion is just to create a string of Field Names for the PIVOT.